# Нужна ли запятая после слова "скажите"?

Tags: пунктуация

Позвоните и скажите(,) сколько и каких ламп надо купить.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Позвоните и скажите, сколько и каких ламп надо купить.*

Запятая нужна, поскольку ***сколько и каких ламп надо купить*** -- придаточное предложение, которое отделяется от главного предложения ***Позвоните и скажите*** запятой.

Придаточные изъяснительные предложения служат для пояснения слова из главной части и отвечают на падежные вопросы (кого? чего? кому? чему? кого? что? кем? чем? о ком? о чем?).
Придаточное изъяснительное может быть присоединено союзами что, чтобы, будто, как, словно, как будто и др. и союзными словами кто, что, который, чей, где, куда, откуда, как, зачем, почему, ***сколько*** (это те же слова, с которых могут начинаться вопросы).

http://www.bitclass.ru/rus/theory/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: Матвей Дёмин, спасибо